# Noble styles and forms of address

Tags: fantasy, word-choice, language

[Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(manner_of_address)) is a manner of address, an honorific that comes with a noble title. For example, HM Elizabeth II is addressed "Your Majesty".

In a fantasy setting that does not pretend to be Europe, I have chosen noble titles that are not "King", "Duke", "Earl", etc., but "Shah", "Vaspahr", "Sardar", etc.

Now I'm trying to understand, **is it right for a Vaspahr to be addressed "Most Noble" and "Your Grace", or are those reserved to a *British* duke?** Would those forms of address sound out of place when used with a non-European title, or are they standard?

Comment: Standard.  Game of Thrones uses Your Grace.  Haven't heard Most Noble but it would fit right in with lots of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noble forms of address were meant to be international. Royals married other royals, so majesty was not just for one House or nation.

There is some variation though, as the Prince of Monaco is Serene Highness.

My Lord and Sir are correct for many.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether it's original, then don't use it. Make something up like noblest Vaspahr, or something of the sort. The titles that you are using aren't bad either, though. The titles that you are, what I think, are reserved for nobility. I don't think it's necessary for you to use these titles, but if you do then don't stress whether it sounds like it should be for a certain court or office. But, again, it's your story.

Comment: I'm not asking whether it is "original", but whether it is *correct*. Those are standard forms used to address people who hold a particular title. What I'm trying to understand is whether "Your Grace", for example, can only be used to address a Commonwealth Duke, or any local equivalent of 'duke'. For example, "Most Christian Majesty" is the style of the French sovereign, and *cannot* be correctly applied to other Christian kings. "Your Majesty", on the other hand, is standard and applies to many kings and queens.

Comment: I'd imagine there are several online resources you can search for this topic.

Comment: The monarch of Spain was called Most Catholic Majesty